# AnyLogic Custom Experiment stuck without any error

Tags: optimization, anylogic

I am using Custom Experiment Optimization in AnyLogic 8.7.2. My model includes optimizing usage of a set of resources (Resource Pool) to meet a certain pre-defined demand. I define my own decision variables and objective function. This Custom Experiment works fine when my model size is small (less number of agents and hence, less decision variables). However, as the model grows in size, the optimization engine seems to get stuck with no warning/error message.

I have tried a few things like increasing the heap size, making the upper bound of decision variables small (varied from 10 to 15) but none of these solutions seem to work.

Any workaround or help on what could be causing this on this would be really useful. Thanks.

Comment: you are maybe abusing memory use... populating a collection forever, creating agents and not deleting them... who knows

Comment: Well, the work is on you. Find out what causes the error and report back. Revert your model to the point where it works and voila: you can now write a question that we might help with :). If it is really only the agent pop size, try to run it in a normal simulation experiment to replicate the issue and investigate. Else, add some trace logs to see when and where the model breaks. You must be the Sherlock Holmes on this ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Simulation experiment works fine from beginning to end. The optimization experiment also works until a couple of iterations (around 10 to 15) beyond which the execution halts in the middle of an iteration without any error message.

Comment: I reached out to the AnyLogic support team. As suggested by them, disabling the option "Log model execution" and "Autoupdate imported tables on model start" resolves the issue. It has also made my individual iterations faster :)